# Dart: How to make GET request with body

Tags: flutter, dart

How to send GET request with body in dart?

I tried all recipes from SO ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331782/flutter-send-json-body-for-http-get-request) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157768/dart-http-get-request-with-body) and more) but with no success.

```
final queryParameters = {
  "id": "6767676767676",
  "device": "tatatata",
  "user": {
    "login": "login",
    "password": "pwd",
  }
};
```

This is complex JSON and i got an error when send request:
`final uri = Uri.http('44.44.444.444:8080', 'get-answer', queryParameters);`

`Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'`

Answer (score 0):

I think your `queryParameters` should not contain objects.

```
final queryParameters = {
    "id": "6767676767676",
    "device": "tatatata",
    "login" : "login",
    "password" : "password",
};
```

Comment: it due to contract. I can not remove object from parameters.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried :

```
var response = await get(url);
var fetchedData = json.decode(response.body);
```

fetchedData will be in a json map format

Answer (score 0):

The answer its actually what Flutter has *suggested* in this part of `exception message` :

> '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'

### What does it mean ?

It means that, one of your *variable* is `'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>'` and flutter wants you to change it to `'Map<String, String>'` type

You should make one of your key in `queryParameters` to this `'Map<String, String>'` type

### How ?

#### 1. Import Dart Convert

by importing `dart:convert`, we will have `jsonEncode` method

```dart
    import 'dart:convert'; // put this at top of your file
```

#### 2. Convert Nested Value, to String

```dart
    final nestedValue = {
        "login": "login",
        "password": "pwd",
      };

    String stringValue = jsonEncode(nestedValue);
```

#### 3. Put it back to your main Parameters

```dart
    final queryParameters = {
      "id": "6767676767676",
      "device": "tatatata",
      "user": stringValue
    };

    final uri = Uri.http('44.44.444.444:8080', 'get-answer', queryParameters);
```

### Final Code

This will be your final code looks like below :

```dart
    import 'dart:convert'; // put this at top of your file


    final nestedValue = {
        "login": "login",
        "password": "pwd",
      };

    String stringValue = jsonEncode(nestedValue); // add this

    final queryParameters = {
      "id": "6767676767676",
      "device": "tatatata",
      "user": stringValue
    };

    final uri = Uri.http('44.44.444.444:8080', 'get-answer', queryParameters);
```

Comment: nope(((
Now parameters successed, but i got error:
`Response body: {..."status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required request body is missing: `
As i can realized `queryParameters` is not really `body`.

Comment: Sure, its different problem. I think you use JSON endpoint right ?, its different than you use now. You better use package dio. But if you find that your previous problem is now solved, Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>', you should accept this as answer then it will closed automatically.

Comment: Thanx, you're right, your advice really helped with Map<...>. I tried dio too, it did not help to solve my "GET with body" issue. Will dig sources ))

Comment: oh I see, previously I had this issue. I had to put Content-type Application/json on the header. and put {} on the body

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) it is perfect for performing http requests.
before sending data make sure you encode you map into json format using the `jsonEncode` function and to obtain the data from a `GET` request decode the body of the request from json format using the jsonDecode function.

- These functions are imported from the `dart:convert` package

```
//import the packages
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

//other code here

final queryParameters = jsonEncode( {
"id": "6767676767676",
"device": "tatatata",
"login" : "login",
"password" : "password",
});

//we send the data to the server with the post method
await http.post("44.44.444.444:8080",queryParameters);

similarly for retrieving data:

final res = http.get("getUrl");

//if the request is successful we get the data
if(res.statusCode == 200)
    final data = jsonDecode(res.body);
```